# jQuery: Setting HTML retrieved thru SJAX call is stopping and breaking up it's parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

### Problem?

While trying to update certain section of my website using **SJAX** and then setting the information gathered thru the request by using jQuery's *.html()* method, it seems to be breaking/stopping it's parent function execution.

### Example!

The function shown below will stop just after trying to perform `.done()`'s callback, leaving the `doSomeStuff()` function left out of execution:

```
function myFunctionUpdater() {

  ...
  ...
  ...

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "/something/somethingelse/anything.jsp",
    async: false
  }).done(function(data) {
    jQuery("#container").html(data);
  });

  ...
  ...
  ...

  doSomeStuff();

}
```

### Workaround!

By setting the updated data into the container using element's *innerHTML* in javascript.

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = data;
```

### Facts!

- jQuery version: 1.8.2
- Data size being received thru **SJAX** request: ~3.2 KB
- Problem appearing: randomly

### Questions!

- Why using `.innerHTML` instead of *jQuery.html()* gets the job done? After all `.html()` uses `.innerHTML` to perform the replace action.
- Is there any reason for the `myFunctionUpdater()` to stop working while trying to set the retrieved HTML data?

Comment: I realy don't remember if `async: false` makes `doSomeStuff();` only executes after the Ajax, but, if you want to run it every time the Ajax calls, put it inside `.always(function(){ doSomeStuff(); })` as the `.done(function(){})`. And, your javascript is inside `$('#container')`? If so, you are overwriting your javascript. Doesn't seems to be the case, through innerHtml works. My last suggestion, substitute `.done` for `.success`.

Comment: @klauskpm: No, my javascript is located in a exernal file. As per the documentation, using SJAX must be completed by using the `success/error/complete` callbacks instead of `done()/fail()/always()` methods of jqXHR.

Comment: Ok. So, if you perform some `alert('stuff after sjax');` it works?

Comment: @klauskpm: It won't work, it just stops while trying to update content using `.html()`

Comment: Ok. Can you show us the output or the response image from your request?

Comment: @klauskpm: The output it's just a `.jsp` with some inline javascript.